# Cambiar string de conexion en una clase C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, windows-forms, .net

Estoy haciendo un programa en C# y estoy por finalizarlo para crear el instalador para instalarlo en otras PC'S pero tengo el string de conexion en una clase llamada baseDatos.cs y quisiera que se pudiera cambiar dicho string de conexion y no encuentro informacion sobre el tema Mi clase baseDatos.cs

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Manfe2
{
    class baseDatos
    {
       private string _servidor;
       private string _instancia;
       private string _baseDeDatos;
       private string _usuario;
private string _password;

public baseDatos()
{
    _servidor = "DESKTOP-IK2PNQC";
    _instancia = "SQLEXPRESS";
    _baseDeDatos = "dbManfe";
    _usuario = "";
    _password = "";
}
```

Comment: La incrustación de cadenas de conexión en el código, puede producir vulnerabilidades. [Trabajar con archivos de configuración](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files) En el enlace dispones de ejemplo sobre como se trabaja con archivos.

Comment: Que tipo de applicacion estas creando  cual framework estas usando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente

como vez la clase llama a App.Config **"connection"**

```
  static private string CadenaConexion = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString;
```

---

Y **"connection"** trae  la configuración de la conexión

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="connection" connectionString="Server=DESKTOP-IK2PNQC; Password=***;user=***;DataBase=dbManfe" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

---

**Código Completo**

Creas la clase

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace DataAccess
{
    public class Conexion
    {
        //nm_acumu
        static private string CadenaConexion = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString;
        private SqlConnection Conexionsql = null;


        public SqlConnection AbrirConexion()
        {
            Conexionsql = new SqlConnection(CadenaConexion);
            if (Conexionsql.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                Conexionsql.Open();
            return Conexionsql;
        }


        public SqlConnection CerrarConexion()
        {
            if (Conexionsql.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                Conexionsql.Close();
            return Conexionsql;
        }

    }
}
```

Desde App.Config, Configuras tu conexión

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="connection" connectionString="Server=DESKTOP-IK2PNQC; Password=***;user=***;DataBase=dbManfe" />
  </connectionStrings>
```